# How do I map Df(w) to it's [lie] group/algebra representation?

Tags: differential-geometry, representation-theory

E.G.

For $p,w\in(\mathbb{R}^3,+,\times_\vartheta)$ with $(\mathbb{R}^3,+)$ a vector space and with $p=(r,s,t)$, $w=(x,y,z)$ where we have $p\times_\vartheta w=(r,s,t)\times_\vartheta(x,y,z)=(rx,sy,rz+ty)$.
Notice this is the matrix multiplication of $p\times_\vartheta w=\begin{pmatrix}r&t\\0&s\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x&z\\0&y\end{pmatrix}$ for the representation $\varphi:(r,s,t)\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}r&t\\0&s\end{pmatrix}$

So we have $f(w)=\left(f(x),f(y),\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}z\right)$ and $Df(w)=\begin{pmatrix}\partial_xf(x)&\partial_yf(x)&\partial_zf(x)\\\partial_xf(y)&\partial_yf(y)&\partial_zf(y)\\\partial_x\left(\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}z\right)&\partial_y\left(\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}z\right)&\partial_z\left(\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}z\right)\end{pmatrix}$

So, $\varphi\left(f(w)\right)=\varphi\left(f(x),f(y),\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}z\right)=\begin{pmatrix}f(x)&\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}z\\0&f(y)\end{pmatrix}$

But can I map $Df(w)$ using the representation $\varphi$?

Comment: What is $f$ here? Is it the exponential map?

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh                                
If using the exp map is more definitive, then let's use $f$ as the exponential map.  More generally, I'm considering any function $f$ such that $f(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n t^n$ is finite for any finite value of $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

My confusion really is that I can find the operator $Df(w)$ for the vector $w$, but not for the representation $\varphi(w)$.

Comment: Ok. So here's what I've got from what you've written. $f$ is some nice function into the matrix group you are looking at and $Df$ is its derivative matrix. You want to figure out what $Df$ looks like as a function into the matrix group. Well, one thing you can do is to take $D(\phi \circ f) = D(\phi)D(f).$